# Create UITextfield With Both Text and Placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4

[image]

I want to create a `UITextField` like above image, with both placeholder in left side and name and Text in right side. Can someone please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Use a background view, inside that take a `label` and a `textfield` placed horizontally.

[image]

Make sure `textField` `borderStyle` is none and `alignment` right.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S don't you think its like making use of 2 different things which is going to be completed in one single thing

Answer (score 1):

You can set this by setting `leftView` to the UITextFiled

You may declared var of IBOutlet for textfield.

```
let textField = UITextField()
```

or

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFiled: UITextFiled!


//create label
let lblName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 80, height: 30))
// --- set other properties to label 

//set right view to text field
textField.leftView = lblName
textField.leftView wMode = .whileEditing
```

You can change `leftViewMode` of the `textField`.